# jQuery toggle open/close symbols

Tags: jquery, dynamic, toggle

How can I get the open/close (i.e., up/down arrows) to work independently in the following code?  Now, they operate in tandem which is misleading. When I 'open' Product A it should then display the up or close arrow which it does but so does Product B which hasn't been 'opened' yet.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">

.productDetails {
    display: none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <td><a href="#" class="expandProductDetails">Product A <span>&darr;</span><span style="display: none;">&uarr;</span></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="productDetails">
                <td><strong>Product Philosophy</strong> Aliquam eu velit nibh. In eleifend convallis ante, sit amet semper arcu lobortis vitae.</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><a href="#" class="expandProductDetails">Product B <span>&darr;</span><span style="display: none;">&uarr;</span></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="productDetails">
                <td><strong>Product Philosophy</strong> Nunc ac nisi vel leo iaculis feugiat. Quisque blandit tempor vestibulum.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

<script>
    $('.expandProductDetails').click(function() {

        $(".expandProductDetails span").toggle();

        $(this).closest("tr").next().slideToggle("slow");

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Working (somewhat) example: http://jsfiddle.net/stulk/mqjuR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(".expandProductDetails span").toggle();
```

to this:

```
$(this).children('span').toggle();
```

`$(".expandProductDetails span")` targets *every* element that has the class `expandProductDetails` (and subsequently selects those elements' child `span` elements. You want to target the child `span` elements of only the element that was clicked which, in the context of your click event, is `this`.

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/mqjuR/5/)